# Can't upload a codename one app on Apple Store anymore

Tags: codenameone

I can't upload my app build with codename one anymore.

I received a mail from Apple

> Missing required icon file - The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro.

What should I do ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a regression with the new xib mode changes mentioned [here](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/no-more-ios-screenshots.html).

Try using the build hint `ios.generateSplashScreens=true` to work around the issue. I suggest removing this hint next week as a fix for this regression will land.

See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/codenameone-discussions/GKomhHhuCz8/K9YC41DFAwAJ